# Why is a basic Twitter bootstrap page too wide on a smart phone?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, smartphone

I'm experimenting privately with adding Bootstrap to my simple website. It's working pretty well out of the box, save for one strange phenomenon: The page is too wide on the small screen size. Here's a screenshot from my HTC One:

[image]

It looks okay when you load it because it zooms in to just the content, but if you scroll up or down and accidentally move your finger to the right, the horizontal scroll activates. The screenshot shows a manual zoom out.

I assumed I had some element on the page that was too wide. But when I loaded the page in a browser and resized that browser to the smallest possible size, I still see this. However, when I inspect the elements, I see that even the top-level `<html>` tag is only 400px wide:

[image]

I'm using the basic viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

What's going on here? I've never seen a page be wider than its `<html>` container.

**Edit, March 14, 4:05PM:**
As an example, I have the bootstrap version of the site live here:

http://labs.mechanicalscribe.com/notes/wikipedia-music-transcriptions/

Comment: I have a similar issue on a new site I just launched using bootstrap responsive.  My padding is less extreme than your screenshot shows...maybe 10-20% of screen width.  Otherwise, it looks great in mobile unless I accidentally drag sideways.  In desktop browsers it looks perfect at all sizes...so the issue is definitely only in mobile and tough to diagnose without firebug (which is how I normally tweak CSS in real-time within my browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kicker{
left: 15px;
width: 800px;
}
```

remove those two css rules and your problem should be fixed

Comment: Just added a live link, thank you. (jsfiddle is too hard to resize).

Comment: @ChrisWilson Can you elaborate on what the solution was here? Have the exact same issue, although no idea what `kicker` refers to/it's nowhere in the Bootstrap CSS

Comment: kicker was in my own CSS. My guess is your non-bootstrap css has something with a fixed width that's too wide.